# How can I average across the values in one column for which all other columns are identical?

Tags: pandas

Let's take this data frame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(json.loads("""[
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 1.0, "name": "kl"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 4.0, "name": "kl"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 3.0, "name": "kl"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 1.0, "name": "kl"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 0.0, "name": "ll"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 4.0, "name": "ll"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 9.0, "name": "ll"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 3.0, "name": "ll"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 2.0, "name": "loss"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 9.0, "name": "loss"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 5.0, "name": "loss"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "train", "value": 4.0, "name": "loss"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 1.0, "name": "kl"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 6.0, "name": "kl"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 3.0, "name": "kl"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 3.0, "name": "kl"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 1.0, "name": "ll"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 2.0, "name": "ll"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 0.0, "name": "ll"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 3.0, "name": "ll"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 1.0, "name": "loss"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 0.0, "name": "loss"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 9.0, "name": "loss"},
{"epoch": 1, "phase": "test",  "value": 4.0, "name": "loss"}]"""))
```

Printing the data frame looks like this:

```
    epoch  phase  value  name
0       1  train    1.0    kl
1       1  train    4.0    kl
2       1  train    3.0    kl
3       1  train    1.0    kl
4       1  train    0.0    ll
5       1  train    4.0    ll
6       1  train    9.0    ll
7       1  train    3.0    ll
8       1  train    2.0  loss
9       1  train    9.0  loss
10      1  train    5.0  loss
11      1  train    4.0  loss
12      1   test    1.0    kl
13      1   test    6.0    kl
14      1   test    3.0    kl
15      1   test    3.0    kl
16      1   test    1.0    ll
17      1   test    2.0    ll
18      1   test    0.0    ll
19      1   test    3.0    ll
20      1   test    1.0  loss
21      1   test    0.0  loss
22      1   test    9.0  loss
23      1   test    4.0  loss
```

For every row that is identical except for the its `value`, I would like to compute the mean (or stddev) over the multiple `value`s:

```
   epoch  phase  value  name
0      1  train   2.25    kl
1      1  train   5.33    ll
2      1  train   5.00  loss
3      1   test   3.25    kl
4      1   test   1.50    ll
5      1   test   3.50  loss
```

Comment: sounds like a generic `groupby` should do it. If you share the contents of `df.head(5)` I can give you the exact syntax

Comment: @Yuca Thanks, that would be great. I've updated the question -- you should be able to either copy the printed data frame or run the code to get the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
df.groupby(['epoch', 'phase', 'name']).mean()
```

Output:

```
                  value
epoch phase name       
1     test  kl     3.25
            ll     1.50
            loss   3.50
      train kl     2.25
            ll     5.33
            loss   5.00
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'm using `df.groupby(list(df.columns.drop('value'))).mean()` now.

Comment: yup, that's a clever way of grouping by everything but the aggregating field, happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

To automatically group by all columns but `value`:

```
df.groupby(list(df.columns.drop('value'))).mean()
```

Same result:

```
                  value
epoch phase name       
1     test  kl     3.25
            ll     1.50
            loss   3.50
      train kl     2.25
            ll     5.33
            loss   5.00
```